# Observing activites of running program from other C program. [Reporting Key Strokes]

Tags: c, linux, gcc, termios, kbhit

I want to monitor a interactive C program (say program1), which is running on one terminal window. and takes input as number (0-9)

As in monitoring I expect : when I will provide input to program1(running on separate terminal) my observer should detect that the key is pressed (from separate terminal).

To achieve that I have to write a C program (observer_prog.c) which will execute on separate terminal waiting for the activities from program1.

I implemented the suggestions from below links for GCC compiler kbhit() function. But it is not able to detect the key strokes from different terminal executions.

[kbhit() implementation for gcc](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=554845)

Is there anyway I can improve this existing module, OR any other workaround for this ?

**Observer Program**

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
static struct termios g_old_kbd_mode;


static int kbhit(void){
struct timeval timeout;
fd_set read_handles;
int status;

// check stdin (fd 0) for activity
FD_ZERO(&read_handles);
FD_SET(0, &read_handles);
timeout.tv_sec = timeout.tv_usec = 0;
status = select(0 + 1, &read_handles, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
return status;
}
static void old_attr(void){
tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &g_old_kbd_mode);
}

void press(){
  printf("Pressed !!!\n");
 }

 // main function
 int main( void ){
char ch;
static char init;
struct termios new_kbd_mode;

if(init)
    return 0;
// put keyboard (stdin, actually) in raw, unbuffered mode
  tcgetattr(0, &g_old_kbd_mode);
  memcpy(&new_kbd_mode, &g_old_kbd_mode, sizeof(struct termios));

new_kbd_mode.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
new_kbd_mode.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
new_kbd_mode.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new_kbd_mode);
atexit(old_attr);

while (!kbhit()){

    if(kbhit()){
        press();
        exit(1);
    }
}
return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

hi I am not sure but you can try changing STDIN to /dev/ttyUSB*(or applicable device node.) as we are reading it from USART. Let us know if it works or not.

Comment: This is more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: I agree but I feel this is the answer.